# Opening a new iframe lightbox of .mov movie from within a flash object, possible?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, iframe

I have a few Flash objects in my html page, and all these Flash objects respond to mouseOver and mouseOut.

On mouseOver, the Flash objects will play a movieclip in place.

On MouseEvent.CLICK, I would like the Flash objects to make the html page create a new iFrame with embedded .mov movie file in a lightbox effect.

I can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried ExternalInterface.call(), navigatetoURL(), I have tried simulating a click event in javascript.

Essentially, I want a mouse-click that is captured in Flash to open a jquery/javascript-lightbox in an iframe.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using `ExternalInterface.call()`.

However, calls to the external API only work if you set the right value for `allowScriptAccess` in your HTML object/embed tags.  Be sure to set `allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"` or `allowScriptAccess="always"`.

Try to call a function containing a simple JavaScript alert first, so you know it's working, before you implement your functionality.